# How to perform Update, Delete operation in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to perform Update and Delete operation in Django rest framework, I did Get and Post operation. I'm new to django, Please help me to do Update and Delete operation.

views.py

```
class StudentViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/student', views.StudentViews)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do those operations(`PUT`,`PATCH` and `DELETE`) in the **`api/student/1234/`** end-point, where the **`1234`** is the **`PK`** of the instance to be deleted or updated.
You can refer more related to the end-point which is created buy the router automatically here, [**DefaultRouter**--[DRF-DOC]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)